# Copy a hidden sheet (which includes shapes that have macros assigned to them) to another sheet and hide the sheet back

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with seven rectangles, each rectangle has a macro assigned to it and I have beautified it like a template.
There are many such sheets and I want them all hidden.

Now, I want to unhide a sheet ,say sheet1, copy all its contents including the shapes and respective macros in the exact same format, paste it in sheet 3 and hide sheet 1 again.

I have tried this with the following code but somehow the objects and the format is not getting copied.

```
Sub abcd()
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
      ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
          ws.Select

          Selection.Copy

      Dim rs As Worksheet
      Set rs = Sheets("Sheet4")
          rs.Select                                              
          ActiveSheet.Paste
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the whole sheet, not just the selection:

```
'// get the sheet to be copied
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1


'// copy it and position before, say sheet5
ws.Copy Before:=Sheet5

'// get a reference to the new sheet
Dim WSNew as worksheet
Set WSNew = Sheets(Sheet5.Index - 1)

'// Give the sheet a new name and make it visible.
WSNew.Name = "New name"
WSNew.Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

Note that I am using the internal sheet programming name, not the display name- that is more reliable as the user cannot change the internal name, although you can change it in the properties tab for the sheet.

Also, there is no need to make the template sheet visible, just the copied one.